# developer options disappear from settings

Tags: android, android-4.2-jelly-bean

After upgrade to Android Jelly Bean 4.2 I couldn't find `developer options` in the settings. What happen to this setting? Where can I find it now?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I found that its hidden in the settings menu to improve user experience. You can activate it at any time by tapping **7** times on **Settings > About phone > Build number**

from official android [documentation](http://developer.android.com/about/versions/jelly-bean.html#42-dev-options):

> On devices running Android 4.2, developer options are hidden by
>   default, helping to create a better experience for users. You can
>   reveal the developer options at any time by tapping 7 times on
>   Settings > About phone > Build number on any compatible Android
>   device.

Comment: Followed those steps, and it still doesn't show up. I get the "you are already a developer" message, but I still don't see the options. Is it because the user account is not the first one on the phone? (If so, how dumb is that?)

Comment: I dont think so... your problem is very strange, it should work

Comment: Also check that you are tapping the Build Number, and not the Android Version - because Android Version also gives you a Jelly Bean 'Easter Egg' thing!

Answer (score 1):

On most devices running Android 3.2 or older, you can find the option under '

```
Settings > Applications > Development.
```

On Android 4.0 and newer, it's in

```
Settings > Developer options.
```

Note: On Android 4.2 and newer, Developer options is hidden by default. To make it available, go to

```
Settings > About phone and tap Build number seven (7) times.
```

Return to the previous screen to find Developer options.

Answer (score 0):

With Android 4.2 onwards, developer options are hidden by default to enhance user experience.

**You can get and enable the developer options at any time by tapping 7 times on Settings > About phone > Build number on any compatible Android device.**

The same has been tested and working fine on Samsung, Sony experia and HTC devices.

Comment: this is the same message as in above